# Placing a visible picture in beamer that doesn't take up any space

Tags: beamer, spacing, graphics, overlays

I am preparing slides with bullet points, and would like to illustrate some of the early ones with a (temporary) picture. Of course, this can be achieved with simple overlays as in

```
\begin{itemize}
\item<+-> Bullet Point 1\\
  \only<+>{\includegraphics{illustration1}}
\item<+-> Bullet Point 2
\end{itemize}
```

There is but one problem: The bullet points jump around on stage 2 to accommodate the additional space taken up by the picture. I understand that this often makes sense, but in this particular instance, I would prefer that the one stage is off-center and instead the Bullet Point 1 always occupies the same position.

Is there a simple command to essentially make the \includegraphics{} command show up but "occupy zero space"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overlayarea`:

```
\begin{overlayarea}{<area width>}{<area height>}
<environment contents>
\end{overlayarea}
```

For more details, consult `beameruserguide` page 84, section 9.5

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.5\textheight}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<+-> Bullet Point 1\\
                \only<+>{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}
      \item<+-> Bullet Point 2
      \end{itemize}
  \end{overlayarea}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solved my question! The only modification I did is to simply put
 `\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0pt} 
  \includegraphics{illustration1}
  \end{overlayare}`
which I find more flexible because I don't have to bound the overall size of my list.